# Ionic platform install error

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic platform, just had to test an app developed in Ionic platform. But I just am not able to install Ionic. Anybody who experienced the same issue please help me out from this.[image: HERE IS THE TERMINAL RESULT]

Answer (score 1):

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

[Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work)