# npm installation error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: node.js, express, npm-install

ive just started working on my first node JS app, while trying to install express through npm, i was getting te following error :

```
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 8080 }
```

and at npm-debug :

```
36 verbose stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
36 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
36 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
36 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
37 verbose cwd C:\APS\NodeJS
38 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
39 error argv "C:\\APS\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "C:\\APS\\NodeJS\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"
40 error node v4.4.0
41 error npm  v2.14.20
42 error code ECONNREFUSED
43 error errno ECONNREFUSED
44 error syscall connect
45 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
45 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
45 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
45 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
45 error  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
45 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
45 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
45 error   syscall: 'connect',
45 error   address: '127.0.0.1',
45 error   port: 8080 }
46 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
46 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
47 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

i looke for tat issue and couldnt find somthing , if anyone that faced such an issue can help ill appriciate it.
TNX

Comment: Can you post the command that you are using to try installing Express with NPM? It's trying to download it from your local computer instead of going out to the internet to get it.

Comment: it was "npm install express"

Comment: do you use any proxy server?

Comment: No, im not using one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Issue solved**

The error was by wrong configuration of proxy on one of my attempts probably. What helped me was: 
[npm install not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work)

I did the following :

1. npm config set proxy **null**
   npm config set https-proxy **null**
2. npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Thanks for everyone trying to help