# Thingsboard Not building from Source

Tags: maven, npm, thingsboard

I have a new ubuntu 16.04 Virtual machine that I'm attempting to install [thingsboard](https://thingsboard.io/) on using this documentation [Contribution Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/how-to-contribute/) and am not having any success:

This is what did did on the machine:

1. `sudo apt-get install default-jre default-jdk`
2. Export `JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/default-java'`
3. `git clone` https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard.git
4. `git checkout release-1.3`
5. `cd ${TB_WORK_DIR}/application`
6. `mvn clean install -DskipTests`
7. Modified `cd ${TB_WORK_DIR}/application/target/bin/install/install_dev_db.sh` to my user and executed script.
   I would like to use HSQLDB at the moment.
8. `cd ${TB_WORK_DIR}/application`
9. `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Results:

NPM server starts but when I log onto `localhost:3000` and attempt to login with `tenant@thingsboard.org` / `tenant`, I get the error

```
[Error API proxy error: Error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
```

I've triple checked that I do not have a typo.

Am I missing a step?

I'm not using a proxy and received the same error as above:

`npm config set proxy null 
 npm config set https-proxy null npm config
 npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

cat ~/.npmrc:

`proxy=null
https-proxy=null
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/ls`

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, this is the same as [thingsboard/thingsboard issue 336](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/336)... 
with the only tip being:

> I think you need the backend running in order to be able to log in.

Either you are [behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25688943/6309)

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
```

Or [you are not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41093731/6309), meaning your localhost thingsboard system should *not* use a proxy at all:

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
```

In both cases:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then try again to re-start your server and to log on.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I'm not using a proxy and I'm logged into the VM and hitting `localhost:3000`

Comment: @risail yet, your `.nprmrc` must include a proxy reference. Remove it from the `.npmrc` and it should work.

Comment: @risail Or do you have any environment variable involving proxy? (http_proxy? ...)

Comment: I posted my `.npmrc` above and followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/526095/how-to-enable-disable-proxy to confirm no proxy along with running `printenv` and confirmed a proxy entry did not creep into the sys.

Comment: @risail OK. Strange. it is as the server expacts/demands a proxy: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/7c6cdb148c3c1b54ee31b477667144675bb45840/ui/server.js#L27-L31

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

1- make sure you have java 8 (JDK not JRE) ,

2- Run "mvn clean install -DskipTests" from root directory (not application directory)

3- hit 127.0.0.1:8080 not :3000 (this one if you build from UI folder)