# npm not working - “read ECONNRESET” when installing angularjs2 cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm

```
E:\Harish\Deploy>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
```

```html
    And i also tried npm registery settings npm config set registry 
    http://registry.npmjs.org/
    
    But it didn't resolve my issue
    
    Any Idea About this?How to overcome this proxy connection settings
```

```
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

And i also tried npm registery settings npm config set registry 
http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I am using Node 8.1.3 and npm 5.0.3. When i Install npm install -g @angular/cli

i am getting connection refused and some proxy errors.I also registered proxy settings in npm registry still i am getting the same proxy connection refused error Please filnd error image as an attachment.

If u are running behind a proxy please make sure that proxy config set properly

How to resolve this issue?

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR! C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log

```
But it didn't resolve my issue

Any Idea About this?How to overcome this proxy connection settings
```

Comment: You need install latest nodejs https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.11.1/node-v6.11.1-x64.msi

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar..  Even i installed node-v6.11.1 also i am facing same above issue

Comment: have you checked node version using node -v.

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar.. Yes using node -v i am using 6.11.1  i am getting ECONREFUSED  and proxy errors like if you are running behind a proxy please make sure that your proxy settings configured properly...Plz help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: please update error log details on your question nodejs version is showing as below. npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8

Comment: you can add me on skype vindhyachal.kumar

Comment: Thnak you for your response right now i am in office i can't use skype here. Can i mail you error screenshot..

Comment: yes, my email id is vks9009@gmail.com

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

Comment: npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.36.162:80
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1
npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.36.162:80
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1

Comment: I think this post will be helpful for you to bypass proxy setting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar...npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport I Tried above commands but still i am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

This works for me.