# Installing NPM Package from Github for SAPUI5 WebIde

Tags: javascript, npm, package, installation, sapui5

I want to install an NPM package from Github so that it can be used in SAPUI5, WebIde Framework.

Package: https://github.com/commenthol/date-holidays/blob/master/README.md#usage

**First Problem** In order to import a Library there should be a File with the Library so it can be copy-pasted in WebIde in the backend.

**Second Problem** The Usage - Part: should this piece of Text be part of the Frontend?

**Third Problem**: Copyright https://github.com/commenthol/date-holidays/blob/master/LICENSE: Author states that it can be used, unless the copyright notice and permission notice appear in all copies. Now if you inspect a Page created by SAPUI5 /NodeJS, you will never ever see any commentaries that were done in the WEBIDE, is it necessary to state it in the Code as a commentary if nobody will see it?

**Fourth Thing on the side**: For Example: npm install express, will Install data into package.json, how do i make it install for example express Pack into example.json instead of package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, the package is available on npm as 
[date-holidays](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-holidays)

you can do `npm i date-holidays`

If you want to install package from github you install it by 
`npm i git+https://github.com/commenthol/date-holidays`

After that

`var Holidays = require(date-holidays);
var hd = new Holidays();
hd.getStates('US');`

and so on, you can use the library as may like.

Comment: Thank you! Also a question on the side. If for example you add to package.json into to dependencies something like "date-holidays": "1.4.2", than will you with the operation npm install date-holidays, get the package?

Comment: if you add the package to package.json, then you only need to run the command npm i or npm install and the package will be installed

Comment: i added "date-holidays": "1.4.2" - to package.json dependencies. There are more dependencies but i would like to only install the date-holidays

Comment: then, first remove `date-holidays` and do `npm i date-holidays -s`, after running this command `date-holidays` will be added to package.json

Comment: what does the npm i do?, the i part i am most interested. Is that just a shortcut for i=install?

Comment: yes `i` is short for `install` and similarly `-s` is `--save`

Comment: will npm uninstall date-holidays undo all the packages regarding date-holidays?

Comment: yes `npm uninstall date-holidays` will remove the package

Comment: Ok npm i date-holidays gives out a fkton of Errors , seems to now work, or the package is questionable

Comment: npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED; npm ERR! FetchError: request: bunch of text/date-holidays failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: are you able to install other packages ? 
I've found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work

Comment: I found another Way: just add "date-holidays": "1.4.2" to package.json and restart backend, refresh Workspace. It will automaticlly pull a folder with all the Data